# Rails has_many and has_one with argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many, has-one

I have a setup like the below:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  has_many :projects_users
  has_many :projects, through: :projects_users  

  ...

end
```

projects_users.rb

```
class ProjectsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user

  has_one :projects_users_role  
end
```

project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects_users
  has_many :users, through: :projects_users
end
```

Users are nested under Project in my routes file.

For some reason, I cannot seem to find a good way of accessing a single project for a user.  Ideally I would like to create a

```
 has_one :project_user
```

association and then a

```
has_one :project, through: :project_user
```

and somehow pass and id for the project to the association (which I know is not possible).  Any ideas for a good approach.

I would then like to call a method similar to

```
   @user = User.includes(:project (project_id parameter).find(:id)
```

in my users controller.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

UPDATE

I essentially have a role that is attached per project per user in the projects_users.rb (updated above and added below)

projects_users.rb

```
class ProjectsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user

  has_one :projects_users_role  
end
```

projects_users_role.rb

```
  class ProjectsUsersRole < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :projects_user
    enum role: [...]
  end
```

And my aim, which I should have stated previously is to be able to edit this role for the user on the given project via a route like

```
  /projects/1/users/2/edit-roles
```

this would display the user, and allow me to assign the role to the projects_users_roles table, with the nested ids added i.e. the id from the project_users table.  Hence I would like (I think) to have a has_one to projects with an argument so that my nested form would be simpler.

Update 2

I have stumbled across this

```
 has_one :project_department, ->(department) { where department: department }, class_name: 'ProjectDepartment'
```

from here http://www.rojotek.com/blog/2014/05/16/cool-stuff-you-can-do-with-rails-has_one/ but cannot make it apply as replacing 'department' with 'project' does not use the project id in the join but the user id in my case.

user.rb *update*

```
...
has_one :project_user, -> (project) { where project: project},    class_name: 'ProjectsUser'
has_one :project, through: :project_user  
...
```

From the console

```
 User.first.project_user(1)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  ProjectsUser Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `projects_users`.* FROM `projects_users` WHERE `projects_users`.`user_id` = 26 AND `projects_users`.`project_id` = 26 LIMIT 1
```

The project_id should be 1 in this case but it is using the user.id 26.  Not sure why really.

Thanks again

Comment: The way it is now, `@user.projects.find(:id)` should work, if I get the right picture, `id` being the id of the project.

Comment: my route at that point in time is /projects/1/user/2 where 1 would be the project_id parameter and 2 the user.id parameter.  Would you suggest doing a 2 line statement like user = User.find(:id) then @project = user.projects.find(:project_id).  Would this generate 2 queries or be clever enough to do just 1?  Thanks

Comment: This will generate two queries. So will writing `User.find(:id).projects.find(:project_id)`. One way to use single SQL statement is in the answer I provide below.

Comment: That is great and will work to a point.  I perhaps should have been more clear.  Please see update

Comment: Thanks for the headache. I can't help you with this right now, but I think the idea would not be very different, scaling a bit up.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that :(...I will give it a try and see where I get.  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm kidding of course. I just don't have something here to test an answer, so I step back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is correct, if you have a model `User`, an argument which is passed to closure is the `self` for called class instance, i.e. it will be an instance of `User`. So in following code piece `project` variable will have a `user` value.

**user.rb**

```
has_one :project_user, -> (project) { where project: project}, class_name: 'ProjectsUser'
```

To pass into `has_many/one` relation an additional argument use extending selector:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :project_user, class_name: 'ProjectsUser' do
      def for_project(project)
         where(project: project)
      end
   end
end

customers.project_user.for_project(project)
```

The approach is described in `Association Extension` head in Rails [`Association`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

One of various ways to produce your result in one SQL statement, would be with a left join:

```
@user=User.joins(:projects).
     where("users.id = ? and projects.id = ?", 
            params[:id], 
            params[:project_id]).take # use take to get one row only
```

**UPDATE**
The above statement will produce an extra SQL request if you want to get:

```
@user.projects.first.id
```

If you want no more statements for the project (of course you don't) you should combine the join with an include:

```
@user=User.joins(:projects).includes(:projects).
     where("users.id = ? and projects.id = ?", 
            params[:id], 
            params[:project_id]).take # use take to get one row only
```

So now

```
@user.projects.first.id
```

will produce no extra SQL statements